# Verifying codecademy course completion

Tags: export

Is there any way to verify that someone who claims they have completed a codecademy course has actually done so? I.e. if someone with the email name@example.com says that they have completed the PHP track on codecademy, is there a way this can be verified? I would imagine that there would be an API for this, something like http://api.codecademy.com/verifyCompletion?email=name@example.com&track=PHP and this would answer true of false depending on if that course has been completed by this person. But can't find any information related to this. Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: I did not attend Codecademy. I'm asking how I can verify that someone else has taken courses on Codecademy.

Comment: If this feature does not exist, maybe they should open up a web service for this.  If they have a website which does this, then you can probably hook into the service.

Comment: No API, but it turns out you can just supply the person's username and it will return their achievements
https://www.codecademy.com/username#completed